# Caesar Cipher C# windows from, not decrypting only encrypting

Tags: c#, windows, caesar-cipher

When I try to decrypt a message, the output isn't what it should be. Could it be a problem with decoding code ?The problem is when you put the shift above 5 it gives a decoding error

Encryption:

`Hello world`

Key:
`20`

Output:
`Byffi qilfx`

Decryption:

`Byffi qilfx`

Key:
`20`

Output `.eRRU ]UXRd` **here error**

This is the encryption code:

```cs
private void encrypt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int keynum = Convert.ToInt32(key_txt.Text);
    string orginalmessage = inputorginaltxt.Text;
    outputCiphertxt.Text = doEncryption(orginalmessage, keynum);
}

private static string doEncryption(string input, int key)
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(input[i]) && char.IsUpper(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - 'A') % 26) + 'A');
            output += ch;
        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(input[i]) && char.IsLower(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - 'a') % 26) + 'a');
            output += ch;
        }
        else if (char.IsNumber(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - '0') % 10) + '0');
            output += ch;
        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(input[i]))
        {
            char d = char.IsUpper(input[i]) ? 'A' : 'a';
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - d) % 26) + d);
            output += ch;
        }
        else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i])) // all alphabets
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - '!') % 95) + '!');
            output += ch;
        }
        else
            output += input[i];
    }
    return output;
}

private void key_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < key_txt.Text.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(key_txt.Text[i])
            || (Convert.ToInt32(key_txt.Text) < 1
                ||  Convert.ToInt32(key_txt.Text) > 25))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Incorrect key, must be enter a value in the range 1 to 25 ",
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            key_txt.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Here error code the decyrpt:

```cs
private void decrypt_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int keynum = Convert.ToInt32(key_txt.Text);
    string Plainmessage = outputCiphertxt.Text;
    outputPlaintxt.Text = doDecryption(Plainmessage, keynum);

}

private static string doDecryption(string input, int key)
{
    string output2 = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(input[i]) && char.IsUpper(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] - key) - 'A') % 26) + 'A');
            output2 += ch;

        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(input[i]) && char.IsLower(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] - key) - 'a') % 26) + 'a');
            output2 += ch;
        }
        else if (char.IsNumber(input[i]))
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] - key) - '0') % 10) + '0');
            output2 += ch;
        }
        else if (char.IsLetter(input[i]))
        {
            char d = char.IsUpper(input[i]) ? 'A' : 'a';
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] - key) - d) % 26) + d);
            output2 += ch;
        }
        else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i])) // all alphabets
        {
            char ch = (char)((((input[i] - key) - '!') % 95) + '!');
            output2 += ch;
        }
        else
            output2 += input[i];
    }
    return output2;
}
}
```

Encryption:

`Hello world`

Key:
`20`

Output:
`Byffi qilfx`

Decryption:

`Byffi qilfx`

Key:
`20`

Output:
`.eRRU ]UXRd` **here error**

Comment: When you subtract a key you might end up with a negative number which can cause problems when you rely on the modulo operator producing a positive value.  Try using the trick of adding the modulus: _e.g._ `(input[i] - key - 'A' + 26) % 26`.  Could be a good idea to treat every character in the equation as `unsigned char` too.  I dunno how C# works, but you tagged this question as C so that's what I'd do in C.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please only add tags that are actually relevant for your question. There is no C code in your question. C and C# are very different languages. Also I don't see how this might be related to winforms. Adding unrelated tags is considered spamming and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from *extracting a method*:

```
  private static char Rotate(char value, int shift, Range range) {
    int mod = (range.End.Value - range.Start.Value + 1);

    return (char) (range.Start.Value + 
      ((value - range.Start.Value + shift % mod) % mod + mod) % mod);
  }
```

Then you can put a *very easy* encryption and decryption routines:

```
 private static string doEncryption(string input, int key) { 
   if (input == null)
     return input;

   return string.Concat(input.Select(c =>
       c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ? Rotate(c, key, 'a'..'z') 
     : c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ? Rotate(c, key, 'A'..'Z') 
     : c >= '0' && c <= '9' ? Rotate(c, key, '0'..'9') 
     : c));
 }

 private static string doDecryption(string input, int key) => 
   doEncryption(input, -key);
```

**Demo:** ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKF0Vf))

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Hello world",
    "key",
    "20",
    "output",
    "Byffi qilfx",
  };

  int key = 20;

  string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => (plain: test, code: doEncryption(test, key)))
    .Select(pair => $"{pair.plain,-12} => {pair.code,-12} => {doDecryption(pair.code, key)}"));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Hello world  => Byffi qilfx  => Hello world
key          => eys          => key
20           => 20           => 20
output       => ionjon       => output
Byffi qilfx  => Vszzc kcfzr  => Byffi qilfx
```

Please, note, that your code

```
    else if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(input[i])) // all alphabets
    {
        char ch = (char)((((input[i] + key) - '!') % 95) + '!');
        output += ch;
    }
```

has a *logical error*: if `input[i] + key` is some *letter* or *digit* (e.g. when `input[i] == '#'` and `key == 20` we `have ch == '7'`) it'll be *decoded* into letter or digit (`'7'` will be decrypted into `7`), not into required symbol (`#`)

Comment: How can I fix the error ,I noticed when the key is set to less than 5, the decryption is correct

Comment: @Zeze Zezo: `(char)((((input[i] - key) - d) % 26) + d);` is *not enough*: if `(input[i] - key) - d) < 0` you'll have problem. Should be `(char)((((input[i] - d) - key % 26 + 26) % 26) + d);`. Have a look at my implementation in `Rotate`: `((value - range.Start.Value + shift % mod) % mod + mod) % mod);`